# Scanning an input and skipping certain characters

Tags: java, arrays, sudoku

I'm scanning a text file that has a sudoku board with a few separators. this is what a sample input would look like.

```
1 - - | 4 5 6 | - - -  
5 7 - | 1 3 b | 6 2 4  
4 9 6 | 8 7 2 | 1 5 3  
======+=======+======  
9 - - | - - - | 4 6 -  
6 4 1 | 2 9 7 | 8 3 -  
3 8 7 | 5 6 4 | 2 9 -  
======+=======+======     
7 - - | - - - | 5 4 8   
8 r 4 | 9 1 5 | 3 7 2   
2 3 5 | 7 4 $ | 9 1 6
```

where it has "|" as borders and =====+====+==== as dividers. I made this code to ignore the | and ====+===+=== but it's skipping that part of the code and declaring them as invalid characters and adding 0's in there place

```
public static int [][] createBoard(Scanner input){

    int[][] nSudokuBoard = new int[9][9];

  for (rows = 0; rows < 9; rows++){

        for (columns = 0; columns < 9; columns++){

            if(input.hasNext()){

                if(input.hasNextInt()){
                    int number = input.nextInt();
                    nSudokuBoard[rows][columns] = number;
               }//end if int

                else if(input.hasNext("-")){
                    input.next();
                    nSudokuBoard[rows][columns] = 0;
                    System.out.print("Hyphen Found \n");
                    }//end if hyphen

                else if(input.hasNext("|")){
                    System.out.print("border found \n");
                    input.next();

                }// end if border
                else if(input.hasNext("======+=======+======")){
                    System.out.print("equal row found \n");
                    input.next();
                }// end if equal row

               else {
                   System.out.print("Invalid character detected at... \n Row: " + rows +" Column: " + columns +"\n");
                   System.out.print("Invalid character(s) replaced with a '0'. \n" );
                   input.next();
               }//end else

            }//end reading file
       }//end column for loop
    }//end row for looop
 return  nSudokuBoard;
}//end of createBoard
```

I talked it over with a tutor but i don't remember his suggestion on how to fix this.

Comment: What did you edit James?

Comment: You can click where it says "edited 1 min ago" to see the edit. In this case he just fixed the formatting on the last line of your code.

Comment: Wow. Neat feature. Thanks Ernest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loops increment the row and column counters even when you are consuming a border or a divider.  So even after you fix other issues (as explained in the previous answer), you will finish filling the matrix before you've read all your input. You need to modify your code to conditionally advance the row and column counters only after you've consumed an integer or a dash. This would mean removing the `for` loops, changing the first `if(input.hasNext())` to a `while`, and adding `rows++` and `columns++` in the places where you've consumed an integer or dash and are setting a value for `nSudokuBoard[rows][columns]`.  You would also need logic to determine when to increment `rows` and when to set `columns` back to `0`.

Also, stylistically speaking, you should rename `rows` to `row` and `columns` to `column`.

Comment: I would try to implement how to count column for each row but i couldt figure that out. but ill try your suggestion to incrementing rows and columns only when i consume a integer and dash

Comment: I think I implemented your suggestion correctly but it's running into errors (ArrayIndexOutOfBounds)

Comment: Whenever you consume either an int or a dash, besides storing the value, do this:  `column++ ; if (column == 9 ) { column = 0 ; row++; } `

Comment: You increment the column each time you see an int or a dash. But if incrementing the column makes it go to 9, then you know you have reached the end of the row, so you reset the column to 0, and increment the row.  This is the only time you increment the row.  The code is as I described above.

Answer (score 1):

The String parameter to `hasNext` is treated as a regular expression.  You need to escape special characters:

```
else if(input.hasNext("\\|")){

else if(input.hasNext("======\\+=======\\+======")){
```

http://ideone.com/43j7R

Comment: Wow. Cool link to the ideone site. thanks ill implement this and follow up.